# Is there a hotkey to go to the next province?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Is there a hotkey for province view mode that wil allow me to move to the next province? I have quite a few and managing some aspects of them would be much easier if i could work my way through all of them one by one with a key

Comment: What aspects exactly are you talking aobut? There are some ways to efficiently manage your provices "in bulk", maybe you were not using the 
"correct" way?

Answer (score 1):

After owning this game, as well as having a quick look through the **[EU4 Controls Page](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Controls)**,
I can safely say there is no way to "goto next province" with a simple hotkey.

Looks like it's back to ye' olde point, click, move, repeat.